# Count invitation response against events and response codes

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this table for **Response Codes:**
[image]

And this table for **invitations:**
[image]

My query so far **gives this:**
[image]

While I want to **achieve this:**
[image]

MY QUERY:

```
SELECT 
      i.eventId
     ,code.responseCode
     ,COUNT(i.attendeeResponse) responseCount
FROM invitations i
LEFT JOIN response_codes code
    ON code.responseCode = i.attendeeResponse
GROUP BY i.eventId, code.responseCode, i.attendeeResponse;
```

## [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb11e/5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct a cartesian product of all `eventId`s and `responseCode`s at first (you can achieve it with `join` without condition):

```
select c.eventId
     , c.responseCode
     , count( i.attendeeResponse ) as responseCount
from ( select distinct t1.responseCode
            , t2.eventId
       from `response_codes` t1
       join `invitations` t2 ) c
left join `invitations` i on c.responseCode = i.attendeeResponse and c.eventId = i.eventId
group by c.eventId, c.responseCode;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb11e/79)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cross join the responsecode table to get the all combinations of eventid and responsecode.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb11e/73)

```
SELECT distinct
      i.eventId
     ,code.responseCode
     ,case when t.responseCount is null then 0 
      else t.responsecount end rcount
FROM invitations i
cross JOIN response_codes code
left join 
(SELECT i.eventId
       ,code.responseCode
       ,COUNT(i.attendeeResponse) responseCount
 FROM invitations i
 JOIN response_codes code
 ON code.responseCode = i.attendeeResponse
 group by i.eventid, code.responsecode) t
on t.responsecode =code.responsecode and t.eventid = i.eventid
order by i.eventid, code.responsecode desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Another lazy way could be:

```
SELECT B.EVENTID,A.RESPONSECODE,
IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INVITATIONS C WHERE C.EVENTID = B.EVENTID AND C.ATTENDEERESPONSE = A.RESPONSECODE),0) AS 'responseCount'
FROM
RESPONSE_CODES A,
INVITATIONS B
GROUP BY A.RESPONSECODE,B.EVENTID
ORDER BY EVENTID ASC,RESPONSECODE DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb11e/121)